# InvalidCastException when remove item in ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf

I am doing a project using WPF and Prims.
When remove category in Categories, an error has occurred.

```
public ObservableCollection<CategoryModel> _categories;
public ObservableCollection<CategoryModel> Categories
{
    get { return _categories; }
    set 
    {
        SetProperty(ref _categories, value);
    }
}

public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
    _journal = navigationContext.NavigationService.Journal;
    var category = navigationContext.Parameters["categoryAdd"] as CategoryModel;
    if (category != null)
        Categories.Add(category);
    category = navigationContext.Parameters["categoryDelete"] as CategoryModel;
    if (category != null)
    {
        foreach(var elm in Categories)
            if (elm.Id == category.Id)
                Categories.Remove(elm); //⇒Error here
    }
}
```

Error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Cannot cast an object of type' System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs' to type 'SaleManager.Wpf.Admin.Models.CategoryModel'. '

Why does this error occur? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change a collection in a `foreach` while reading this collection.

you can do this:

```
var item = Categories.FirstOrDefault(elm=> elm.Id == category.Id);
Categories.Remove(item);
```

Comment: Note that this solution unnecessarily iterates the collection twice.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop and iterate backwards. `elm` is supposed to be a `CategoryModel`:

```
if (category != null)
{
    for (int i = Categories.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        CategoryModel elm = Categories[i];
        if (elm.Id == category.Id)
        {
            Categories.Remove(elm);
        }
    }
}
```